# Patch Status for 'cweagans/composer-patches'?

Tags: drush, composer

It seems that 'Drush Patch File' (https://bitbucket.org/davereid/drush-patchfile/src/master/) isn't compatible with Drush 9. It, however, has one important function - Patch Status - which enables developers to check that all the required patches were successfully applied.

I was unable to find any way how to do this via the actually recommended Composer patch management (cweagans/composer-patches)... Is there any way how to (via Composer or Drush command) check the status of the patches? Or is there a clone of 'Drush Patch File' working with Drush 9?

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote? There were several situations when the plugin didn't work correctly (e.g. Composer didn't exit on patch failure) and I didn't find any means how to check that all the patches were applied into the codebase. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gitlab.com/davereid/drush-patch is now available which is the Drupal 8 + composer-patches port of my exising drush-patchfile.

Answer (score 1):

I found no available solution, so I've created a new Drush Command for this: https://github.com/SeoGow/patch_overview/tree/master.

I hope this helps somebody.